# What are the problems of setting MaxRequestsPerChild to 1 of mpm_prefork module

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi, mpm-prefork

For my application I had to have this configuration for it works :

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module> 
    MaxRequestsPerChild   1
</IfModule>
```

What are the problem that I can encounter with this configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be very slow. The process that serves your requests will be restarted after every request (see [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestsperchild)). Normally, this is not necessary.

Something is wrong with your application if it requires constant process restarting.

Answer (score 2):

[`MaxRequestsPerChild`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestsperchild) controls the number of request the a child serves before the child is killed. This should not be set too low as it will put an unnecessary load on Apache.